# Pandas regex match part of string to replace whole string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to update some strings in pandas columns that have variable endings which need to all be uniform.

Example string: "Latest 52 Weeks Ending 07-03-22"

Replacement String: "Latest 52 Wks - W/E 07/03/22"

The example string text may variate the final date (e.g. 07-04-22) but I want all "Latest 52 Weeks" to follow the same format as above. I have tried code similar to the following:

```
df['Current Timeframe'] =  [re.sub(r'Latest 52 Weeks.',date52, str(x)) for x in df['Current Timeframe']]
```

but this ends up with an output like "Latest 52 Wks - W/E 07/03/22Ending 07-03-22" where a portion of the old string is retained at the end.

Comment: can you show your example df?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas version of string replace into your series.

```
df['Current Timeframe'] = df['Current Timeframe'].str.replace("Latest 52 Wks - W/E", "Latest 52 Weeks Ending")
```